# Validate new user email name matching a pattern on registration

Tags: users, emails, forms

Upon new user registration, how could I validate that the email address has a ".edu" extension? Basically, I need to ensure that users are using only their ".edu" email addresses to register for accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, add a validate to user_registration_form and then in validate check email with your pattern and if not match use form_set_error. something like below

```
function registration_check_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    $form['#validate'][] = 'registration_check_user_register_validate';
}
function registration_check_user_register_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
        $email=$form_state['values']['email']['und'][0];
        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)\.edu/i",$email))
                {
                form_set_error('mail', t('Email NOT VALID,TRY EMAIL WITH .EDU'));
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but I ended up writing a Javascript based solution. Essentially, it looks for the string `.edu` in the email address on `blur` of the email field and `click` of the submit button. If it doesn't find it, it prevents the form from being submitted. It looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    function eduCheck() {
        if (jQuery('#edit-mail').val()) {
            if (jQuery('#edit-mail').val().indexOf('.edu') != -1) {
                // alert('Edu present');
            } else {
                alert('Please use a .edu email address only.');
                return false;
            };
        };
    }

    jQuery('#edit-mail').blur(function() {
        eduCheck();
    });

    jQuery('#edit-submit').click(function() {
        eduCheck();
    });

});
</script>
```

Like I said, it's not ideal. But it's a suitable alternative... especially since I couldn't get any of the other suggestions on this page to work.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you can use the [Rules Forms Module](https://drupal.org/project/rules_forms) (dependent on the [Rules Module](https://drupal.org/project/rules))

You can state specific conditions during specific events with specific outcomes.  I would also suggest installing the [Token Module](https://drupal.org/project/token) if you don't already have it.

You can of course do this manually by making a tiny module that validates the User Account form on submission with a simple `stripos()` like so:

```
if(stripos($emailField, '.edu', strlen($emailField) - 4) > 3) {
    // Success...
} else {
    // Failed - email doesn't end in .edu
}
```

This of course uses `$emailField` as the submitted field containing the user's e-mail address.

Comment: Thanks! Can you expand a bit on how one might use the Rules Forms Module. I've got it installed. I've got it set on the event "Before saving a user account", but now I'm stumped; none of the available actions seem relevant.